# Crisp Gif images

Tags: animation, motion-graphics

I am working on a small gif image and I am finding it difficult to get a crisp gif output. The final output looks all blurred. I am using after effects to make the png sequence and using photoshop cc to convert it into a gif image. Please let me know if there is any way to attain a crisp output.

[image: This is the final quality I expect]

[image]

Comment: The GIF format isn't made for crisp animation .. since true GIFs save every frame individually, you will have to use a ridiculously high bitrate and end up with a huge file ... does it have to be a GIF? A video format would work much better

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MoritzLost . I will consider that option.

Answer (score 1):

Try folowing steps:

1. Disable anti-aliasing in After Effects
2. Find some fonts with embedded bitmaps (like Tahoma) which looks good after it
3. Output can be almost in every format with no  quality loss (for small animations you can even use unsompressed AVI), then you can join all it in ImageMagick, it can optimize your palette.
4. Don't use/try to avoid any shadows, alpha-blending or gradients
5. For smaller size, try to avoid to much image changes (as you have).

If you publish your scene, I can try to render it.